# Unexpected segmentation fault when using function decorator (using closure) in c++

Tags: c++, lambda, closures, decorator

I created `decorator` function to add functionality to existing functions. The program outputs correct function pointer addresses along with an elapsed time to iterate 10 x `helloworld` as expected.

Yet, if I change `decorator` function to take the `original_function` by value (`FunctionPointer original_function`), the program terminates with a segmentation fault, which I don't get the reason why it fails.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

typedef void (*FunctionPointer)();

auto
decorator(FunctionPointer && original_function) // if changed to FunctionPointer original_function, it causes segmentation fault when the closure(lambda expression) is called later on
{
    std::cout << "Decorator: " << (void*)original_function << std::endl; // 0x558072fb0b90
    return [&]()
    {
        std::cout << "Decorator: " << (void*)original_function << std::endl; // 0x558072fb0b90 but 0x0 when original_function passed by value
        auto t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        original_function();

        auto duration = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - t0;

        std::cout << "\nElapsed " << duration.count() * 1000.0f << " ms\n";
    };
}


void
helloworld(void)
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
}

int
main(void)
{
    std::cout << "Main: " << (void*)helloworld << std::endl; // 0x558072fb0b90

    auto my_helloworld = decorator(helloworld);
    my_helloworld();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use double reference in the decorator function arguments ("original function"). FunctionPointer is of pointer type and thus is essentially by its self a referential type.

Comment: @Strongwill That is exactly what I expected it to work like. But once it is passed by value, the lambda does not seem to capture the function pointer address. It's set to 0x0 and this is what I want to ask here. Do you know what's happening under the hood?

Answer (score 5):

The difference is that when you pass the function by value, the parameter passed into the lambda is a reference *to the function parameter*, which goes out of scope when `decorator` returns.  When you later call the returned lambda, you reference this out of scope variable, which is Undefined Behavior.

It works when you pass by universal reference, the parameter passed to `decorator` is a reference, which is passed to the lambda.  So it is still valid later when you call the lambda.

You may be able to change your lambda to pass by value (use `[=]`) to get the changed version to work.

Comment: Thanks very much. Such a simple and clear answer. Highly appreciate it.

I think I need to spend some more time working on lambda expression.